# PyPy performance falling off dramatically

Tags: python, memory, triangulation, pypy, voxel

I am working on a voxelization for STL models based on sparse voxel octrees.
I have a 3D Array with around 100,000 triangles (each has 3 points with x,y,z value for each point).

I need to calculate a few points and values for each triangle.
I wrote this algorithm in standard CPython and it took 3 secs to run, that was way to slow for me (around 0,5 s would be good).

I switched to PyPy as a JIT Compiler and it performed very well.
If I run the code without Set A of points/values (see Code) for each triangle (calculate the bounding box and normal) it outperformed CPython by factor 10 and more and if I run the code without Set B of points it outperformed CPython as well. The moment I run the algorithm with both sets it runs way slower than CPYthon (or Set A solo + Set B solo combined).

Do you have any idea what the problem is right there?
I thought it might be a problem with the memory. I assigned more heap memory to pypy in the vm options, didnt work. I deleted all variables after the loop iteration (with "del") didnt work.

I use Windows 10 Home Version 10.0.18363 on a x64 based machine.

I use pypy3.6-v7.3.2rc1-win32 in PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.2

Those are the Vm options:

```
-Xmx2048m
-Xms750m 
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-XX:CICompilerCount=2
-Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off
-Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true
```

Thank you very much for every suggestion.

```
import trimesh as tr
import sys
import datetime

def doT(a,b):
    res=a[0]*b[0]+a[1]*b[1]+a[2]*b[2]
    return res

def doT2(a,b):
    res=a[0]*b[0]+a[1]*b[1]
    return res

def minus (a,b):
    res=[a[0]-b[0],a[1]-b[1],a[2]-b[2]]
    return res

def plus (a,b):
    res = [a[0] + b[0], a[1] + b[1], a[2] + b[2]]
    return res
def crosS(a,b):
    res=[a[1]*b[2]-a[2]*b[1],a[2]*b[0]-a[0]*b[2],a[0]*b[1]-a[1]-b[0]]
    return res

def miN(a,b):
    if a<b:
        return a
    else:
        return b

def maX(a,b):
    if a>b:
        return a
    else:
        return b

trim=tr.load("Stanford_Bunny.stl")
trim.rezero()
triangle_list_tr=trim.triangles
triangle_list=triangle_list_tr.tolist()

for triangle in triangle_list:
    'vertices of surface triangle'
    P1 = triangle[0]
    P2 = triangle[1]
    P3 = triangle[2]

    n = crosS(minus(P1, P2), minus(P3, P2))
    n_sum = n[0] + n[1] + n[2]
    n[0] = n[0] / abs(n_sum)
    n[1] = n[1] / abs(n_sum)
    n[2] = n[2] / abs(n_sum)

    P1x = triangle[0][0]
    P1y = triangle[0][1]
    P1z = triangle[0][2]
    P2x = triangle[1][0]
    P2y = triangle[1][1]
    P2z = triangle[1][2]
    P3x = triangle[2][0]
    P3y = triangle[2][1]
    P3z = triangle[2][2]
    counter+=1
    
    #Set A start
    bbxmin = min(P1x, P2x, P3x)
    bbxmax = max(P1x, P2x, P3x)
    bbymin = min(P1y, P2y, P3y)
    bbymax = max(P1y, P2y, P3y)
    bbzmin = min(P1z, P2z, P3z)
    bbzmax = max(P1z, P2z, P3z)
    #Set A End
    
    #Set B Start
    P1_xy = [P1[0], P1[1]]
    P2_xy = [P2[0], P2[1]]
    P3_xy = [P3[0], P3[1]]
    
    if n[2] >= 0:
        e_xy_12 = [-1 * (P1[1] - P2[1]), P1[0] - P2[0]]
        e_xy_23 = [-1 * (P2[1] - P3[1]), P2[0] - P3[0]]
        e_xy_31 = [-1 * (P3[1] - P1[1]), P3[0] - P1[0]]
    else:
        e_xy_12 = [-1 * (P2[1] - P1[1]), P2[0] - P1[0]]
        e_xy_23 = [-1 * (P3[1] - P2[1]), P3[0] - P2[0]]
        e_xy_31 = [-1 * (P1[1] - P3[1]), P1[0] - P3[0]]

   
    P1_xz = [P1[0], P1[2]]
    P2_xz = [P2[0], P2[2]]
    P3_xz = [P3[0], P3[2]]
    
    if n[1] >= 0:
        e_xz_12 = [-1 * (P2[2] - P1[2]), P2[0] - P1[0]]
        e_xz_23 = [-1 * (P3[2] - P2[2]), P3[0] - P2[0]]
        e_xz_31 = [-1 * (P1[2] - P3[2]), P1[0] - P3[0]]
    else:
        e_xz_12 = [-1 * (P1[2] - P2[2]), P1[0] - P2[0]]
        e_xz_23 = [-1 * (P2[2] - P3[2]), P2[0] - P3[0]]
        e_xz_31 = [-1 * (P3[2] - P1[2]), P3[0] - P1[0]]
    
    

    P1_yz = [P1[1], P1[2]]
    P2_yz = [P2[1], P2[2]]
    P3_yz = [P3[1], P3[2]]
    
    if n[0] >= 0:
        e_yz_12 = [-1 * (P1[2] - P2[2]), P1[1] - P2[1]]
        e_yz_23 = [-1 * (P2[2] - P3[2]), P2[1] - P3[1]]
        e_yz_31 = [-1 * (P3[2] - P1[2]), P3[1] - P1[1]]
    else:
        e_yz_12 = [-1 * (P2[2] - P1[2]), P2[1] - P1[1]]
        e_yz_23 = [-1 * (P3[2] - P2[2]), P3[1] - P2[1]]
        e_yz_31 = [-1 * (P1[2] - P3[2]), P1[1] - P3[1]]
    #Set B End

    del bbxmin
    del bbxmax
    del bbymin
    del bbymax
    del bbzmin
    del bbzmax
    del P1x
    del P1y
    del P1z
    del P2x
    del P2y
    del P2z
    del P3x
    del P3y
    del P3z
    del P1_xy
    del P2_xy
    del P3_xy
    del P1_xz
    del P2_xz
    del P3_xz
    del P1_yz
    del P2_yz
    del P3_yz
    del P1
    del P2
    del P3
    del e_yz_12
    del e_yz_23
    del e_yz_31
    del e_xz_12
    del e_xz_23
    del e_xz_31
    del e_xy_12
    del e_xy_23
    del e_xy_31
```

Comment: I see you import numpy. This will run slowly under PyPy, since it is written with heavy use of the Python C-API. Perhaps `trimesh` is also using the C-API, I am not familiar with it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I knwo that numpy and other C-APi based packages will slow down the pypy performance. I use trimesh to import the STL File. The performance differences described appear in a different part of the programm, but you are right a way aorund trimesh would be perfect. Numpy isn't used (except in the trimesh part) anymore and the import is just a leftover of an older version. Ill edit the post accordingly and delete the import.

Answer (score 0):

Pypy is slower if code has lot of nested if else. CPython is already way more optimized for if else. If you use python the proper way (not like C) then pypy will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your loop into function. And better, wrap body loop into function as well. There's non-zero probability it will help, and for bonus `del XX` would not be needed.